# Trouble with 3D axis in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I have texlive 2012 and have drawn a curve in three dimensions with pgfplots. That has not been a problem. The axes occurs in a way not appear well suited. In the code I indicated that ymax = 1.5, however the figure shows that the maximum value of y is 8. Something similar happens with ymin. Also I have a problem with caption space. Can anyone tell me any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale=1.5,axis equal,view={95}{50},
  axis lines=center,
  axis on top,
  xmin=-3.5,xmax=3.5,
  ymin=-0.5,ymax=1.5,
  zmin=-3,zmax=3,
  xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},zlabel={$z$},
  every axis x label/.style={
  at={(axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0,0)},
  xshift=-0.6em,yshift=-0.1em                 
  },
  every axis y label/.style={
  at={(axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax},0)},
  xshift=0.6em,yshift=-2ex            
  },
  every axis z label/.style={
  at={(axis cs:0,0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmax})},
  xshift=-0.2em,yshift=1em           
  }
  ]
  \addplot3[blue,domain=-3:3,samples y=0] ({x},{x^2/(1+x^2)},{x^3/(1+x^2)});
  \legend{$\Ran f$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Gráfico de (x,x²/(1+x²),x³/(1+x²))]

Comment: The `axis equal` key modifies the axis limits. Remove it, and you'll get the limits you specified. According to the `pgfplots` manual on the `axis equal` key: *Each unit vector is set to the same length while the axis dimensions stay constant. Afterwards, the size
ratios for each unit in x and y will be the same.
Axis limits will be enlarged to compensate for the scaling effect.*

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion gives an acceptable result, however the problem with caption space still continues.

Comment: What is the problem with the caption space? You've told us you have the problem but you haven't described the issue. Also, it is likely not `pgfplots`-related, but more likely related to how you are creating the subfigures/captions. Please update the MWE to show these things.